# Is it possible to use a superclass as the generic paratemer entity of a Spring Data Mongo repository?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Normally we would define Spring Data repositories like this:

```
@Repository
interface SomeEntityRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<SomeEntity, String>
```

However my domain has a bunch of entities that extend a common base class. Let's suppose for this case `Car` extends `Vehicle` (an abstract base class) and there are a lot of other kinds of vehicles, so I would like to have only one Spring Data repository for all of them:

```
@Repository
interface VehicleRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<Vehicle, String>
```

```
@Document
class Car(@Id val id: String, xxx) : Vehicle(xxx)
```

```
@Document
class Motorbike(@Id val id: String, xxx) : Vehicle(xxx)
```

```
abstract class Vehicle(val xxx)
```

Is this possible or is there a way to tweak the entities to support something like this?

Comment: Have you tried it? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: The repository for abstract entity returns no entities for me in this scenario

Comment: In my case the repository for the abstract class inserts all types (Car, Motorbike) in the same collection (Vehicle), adding a _class attribute with the concrete class name. I would like to keep them in separated collections per concrete entity.